# How do I match long text strings with a partial text string in order to create categories in excel

Tags: excel-formula

How do I search a data-set for partial-text matches?

In the specific example, I want excel to search the `R-column` for partial text strings that might match the text in cell `L3` and return the partial text from the `R-column` in the `O-column`.

[image: specific example]

So for instance in cell `O3` I want the partial text string **"Avgift"**.

Do anyone know a formula for this?

Br,
Karoline

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Have you tired to solve your problem by yourself? If so please post the formula or functions you have tried. If you have no idea where to start, here are a couple functions that may help you: **FIND**, **SEARCH**, **MATCH**, **INDEX**.

Comment: @Karoline: I made several edits to my formula to match the cells' locations in your graphic example, which was difficult to see. I then enlarged it.

Answer (score 0):

Insert this Formula in Cell O3 and copy down as far as needed to get your partial strings:

=IF(COUNT(SEARCH(R3,L$3:L$10,1))>0,R3,"").